# Resizing tables in Latex

Tags: tables

I have a problem with fitting two tables in my TEXSHOP File to the right size. Below I attached a screeshot, showing that the table is clearly too small to be visible. My code is the following:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering 
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular} {|| l | l ||}
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Benefits of participatory sensing}
\label{benefits}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Many 
Many thanks for your help,
Hugo

Comment: replace `l` by `p{4cm}` or whatever column width you need and remove the adjustbox scaling. scaling tables should be an absolute final resort (and even then consider not doing it)

Comment: Please give us some compilable code and put some text in your table. It is much easier to help then.

Answer (score 2):

Do not scale tables if not necessary. If you have that much text, you could also write it as an itemization or by using paragraphs or something alike.

In order to get the maximum width, I would recommend the package `tabularx` here:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}    
\begin{table}
    \centering 
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l>{\RaggedRight}X@{}} % @{} takes away any horizontal spacing at the borders. Not beautiful, but gives you some more space. 
        \toprule
        bla bla blup & \blindtext\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Benefits of participatory sensing}\label{benefits}
\end{table} 
\setcounter{section}{3}
\setcounter{subsection}{2}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{2}
\subsubsection{Challenges or participatory sensing}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you want to tweak your first column to have the width of your desired definition, you should replace the `l` by `p{<some dimension>}`. In this case and if you like the columns to be set `\RaggedRight` as I did in my MWE above, you might want to load `ragged2e` as `\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}`.